# div не прокручивается при фиксированном body

Tags: css, background

весь мозг уже сломал...
задача: закрепить фоновое изображение для body, а в центре поместить какой-нибудь текст, чтобы текст был длиннее, чем высота экрана, и соответственно была полоса прокрутки, но чтобы фон оставался неподвижным.
проблема в том, что текст выходит за границы экрана и полоса прокрутки не появляется. мне нужно, чтобы размер текста устанавливался в 4vh, например.

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

    <div>
    тут например стих пушкина
    мороз и солнце, день чудесный</br>
    еще ты дремлешь, друг прелестный</br>

и так далее...

    </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(red, blue);
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

```html
<main>
весь мозг уже сломал... задача: закрепить фоновое изображение для body, а в центре поместить какой-нибудь текст, чтобы текст был длиннее, чем высота экрана, и соответственно была полоса прокрутки, но чтобы фон оставался неподвижным. проблема в том, что текст выходит за границы экрана и полоса прокрутки не появляется. мне нужно, чтобы размер текста устанавливался в 4vh, например.
весь мозг уже сломал... задача: закрепить фоновое изображение для body, а в центре поместить какой-нибудь текст, чтобы текст был длиннее, чем высота экрана, и соответственно была полоса прокрутки, но чтобы фон оставался неподвижным. проблема в том, что текст выходит за границы экрана и полоса прокрутки не появляется. мне нужно, чтобы размер текста устанавливался в 4vh, например.
весь мозг уже сломал... задача: закрепить фоновое изображение для body, а в центре поместить какой-нибудь текст, чтобы текст был длиннее, чем высота экрана, и соответственно была полоса прокрутки, но чтобы фон оставался неподвижным. проблема в том, что текст выходит за границы экрана и полоса прокрутки не появляется. мне нужно, чтобы размер текста устанавливался в 4vh, например.
весь мозг уже сломал... задача: закрепить фоновое изображение для body, а в центре поместить какой-нибудь текст, чтобы текст был длиннее, чем высота экрана, и соответственно была полоса прокрутки, но чтобы фон оставался неподвижным. проблема в том, что текст выходит за границы экрана и полоса прокрутки не появляется. мне нужно, чтобы размер текста устанавливался в 4vh, например.
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body, main {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background: linear-gradient(red, blue);
}

main {
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<main>
весь мозг уже сломал... задача: закрепить фоновое изображение для body, а в центре поместить какой-нибудь текст, чтобы текст был длиннее, чем высота экрана, и соответственно была полоса прокрутки, но чтобы фон оставался неподвижным. проблема в том, что текст выходит за границы экрана и полоса прокрутки не появляется. мне нужно, чтобы размер текста устанавливался в 4vh, например.
весь мозг уже сломал... задача: закрепить фоновое изображение для body, а в центре поместить какой-нибудь текст, чтобы текст был длиннее, чем высота экрана, и соответственно была полоса прокрутки, но чтобы фон оставался неподвижным. проблема в том, что текст выходит за границы экрана и полоса прокрутки не появляется. мне нужно, чтобы размер текста устанавливался в 4vh, например.
весь мозг уже сломал... задача: закрепить фоновое изображение для body, а в центре поместить какой-нибудь текст, чтобы текст был длиннее, чем высота экрана, и соответственно была полоса прокрутки, но чтобы фон оставался неподвижным. проблема в том, что текст выходит за границы экрана и полоса прокрутки не появляется. мне нужно, чтобы размер текста устанавливался в 4vh, например.
весь мозг уже сломал... задача: закрепить фоновое изображение для body, а в центре поместить какой-нибудь текст, чтобы текст был длиннее, чем высота экрана, и соответственно была полоса прокрутки, но чтобы фон оставался неподвижным. проблема в том, что текст выходит за границы экрана и полоса прокрутки не появляется. мне нужно, чтобы размер текста устанавливался в 4vh, например.
</main>
```

Comment: премного благодарен.

Comment: @user268787, если проблема решена, прими один из ответов нажатием на галочку слева от него.